# What exactly does BitwiseXNOR mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, eflags

In [x86 TEST instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_315.html), we have the following operations:

```
Temporary = Source1 & Source2;
SF = MSB(Temporary);
if(Temporary = 0) ZF = 1;
else ZF = 0;
PF = BitwiseXNOR(Temporary[0:7]);
for(PF = 1, i = 0; i < 8; ++i) PF ^= Temporary[i];
CF = 0;
OF = 0;
AF = Undefined;
```

I don't get how is `BitwiseXNOR(Temporary[0:7]` calculated. I know what `XNOR` does and what is its truth table, but doesn't `XNOR` always need *two* operands? And more importantly, PF is just one bit, how does a bitwise calculation of 8-bit results in a 1-bit flag?

Comment: It XNORs all 8 bits together. Notice the `for` loop, that is what it is doing. Not sure why both are given.

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot, now that makes a lot of sense. BTW this is probably a misunderstanding, but isn't `^=` AND instead of XNOR?

Comment: `^` is XOR, the N comes from initializing PF with 1. AND is `&`.

Comment: The official Intel manual only has the `BitwiseXNOR` line, not the redundant `for` line.  So I don't know where c9x.me got the latter.  It also doesn't match the syntax that the Intel manuals use for a for loop, which would look more like `FOR i := 1 TO 8 .... ENDFOR`.

Comment: there's no `for` here https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test

Comment: *PF is just one bit, how does a bitwise calculation of 8-bit results in a 1-bit flag?* - it's a reduction, a "horizontal" XNOR.  Just like how ZF is set to `!horizontal_or(temporary)`, i.e. a wide NOR of all the bits (not just the low 8).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit